# Can I use a GitHub project directly in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, github

I am interested in using a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/toelen/spymemcached-jcache) as a dependency in my project. The GitHub project has a `pom` file. Can I modify my `pom` file to use this project? If so, how? If not, what is my best course of action?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not in the way I think you mean, AFAIK.

You can use [github as a Maven repository](http://alexsotob.blogspot.com/2011/09/questa-di-marinella-e-la-storia-vera.html)--this is not the same thing as directly referencing a project, and that it has a pom file means only that it's a Maven project.

*If* the project is not available in the central, or other, repository, your best bet may be to clone it, build it, and [install it locally](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). You should confirm that it's truly not available elsewhere.

Comment: Downvoting a once-correct answer may not be the best approach.

Comment: Heroku also provides a nice setp-by-step guide on [adding unmanaged dependencies to a Maven project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies).

Answer (score 151):

Try [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/), you just need to add the dependency, jitpack will build others for you.

From home page:

> jitpack
>   Easy to use package repository for Gradle and Maven projects
>   JitPack builds GitHub projects on demand and provides ready-to-use packages

### HOW

1. Add repository first

```xml
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

2. Add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.User</groupId>
    <artifactId>Repo name</artifactId>
    <version>Release tag</version>
</dependency>
```

TIPS:

You can see its build log too https://jitpack.io/com/github/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/Release-2.1.0/build.log

Comment: @james free for public git repositories

Comment: I can't make it work. I am trying   <!-- https://github.com/lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java.git -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.lbehnke</groupId>
   <artifactId>hierarchical-clustering-java</artifactId>
   <version>anyBranch-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency> 

is that right?

Comment: Does `jitpack` work for multiple repos in one `pom.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

@wener's answer is very helpful, but leaves some mystery.

This real example might save some time:

```
<project ... >
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>

            <!-- groupId is https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client -->
            <groupId>com.github.fabric8io.kubernetes-client</groupId>

            <!-- module is a directory within the repo, containing pom.xml -->
            <artifactId>kubernetes-model-generator-client</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

 . . .
```

Make sure you are signed into GitHub.

You can also find a tag index page by cutting at the tag within the URL, like  https://jitpack.io/com/github/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/. In my example, I figured out if "v" from "v6.4.1" had to be removed or not, since there is a release with the v and a tag without it.

More details: [jitpack.io page](https://jitpack.io/docs/BUILDING/#maven-projects)