# How to add Orchid module as maven dependency then generate build

Tags: java, maven

I downloaded Orchid from https://subgraph.com/orchid/download/index.en.html
I added it as a module to my project. In my project's pom I have

```
<groupId>com.subgraph</groupId>
<artifactId>orchid</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

The module is added to classpath. But when I'm trying mvn:deploy I get the error:

> Could not find artifact com.subgraph:orchid:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   What should I do to make deploy task available?

Comment: Please explain better what you mean by adding a module? Do you mean a dependency? When do you get the error? When running mvn deploy, or when running your app?

Comment: I added module as a dependency. I get the error when I run mvn deploy

Comment: @Loco were you able to set orchid as a dependency? can you post the answer?

Comment: @Arbi here is the example where orchid is used
https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/orchid/pom.xml
https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/core/pom.xml#L470

Comment: @Loco they used orchid as a maven module for bitcoinj (without [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)), may be something like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161602/loading-maven-dependencies-from-github) would be better!