# google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all 1.8 dost not include ValueProvider

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I develop sotfware by using Dataflow Java SDK in Eclipse.
I check the master branch of DataflowJavaSDK,
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK,
but some sources like ValueProvider are not included in latest google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all version 1.8.
Does it means master branch code should not use?
I would like to get master branch library via Maven.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releases are cut roughly monthly from the DataflowJavaSDK repository, so you may find commits there that are ahead of the most recent release.  You can see which commits correspond to given releases here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/releases

It's also fine to use the code at head, though you can expect that maven releases have undergone additional testings and may be more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to Dataflow, there are some possible answers for your maven question at "[Loading Maven dependencies from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161602/loading-maven-dependencies-from-github)".