# Maven dependency on an artifact for which I have an active pull request

Tags: maven

I would like to keep a project close to the clean/approved maven process. I have an active PR for a performance improvement against one of the dependencies that I would like to include.

What is the cleanest/ most approved maven way to reference the code from the PR?

Some thoughts that came to mind:

- Does maven have a means to reference a PR directly?
- Or maybe a local patch instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution ended up being using jitpack, https://jitpack.io/

as described in an answer on this SOF:

[Can I use a GitHub project directly in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871056/can-i-use-a-github-project-directly-in-maven)

```
Add repository first
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
Add dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.User</groupId>
    <artifactId>Repo name</artifactId>
    <version>Release tag</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependencies do not comprise source code but artifacts created by builds. See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.4. Project Dependencies](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#performing-a-snapshot-deployment):

> *Maven can manage both internal and external dependencies. An external dependency for a Java project might be a library such as Plexus, the Spring Framework, or Log4J. An internal dependency is illustrated by a web application project depending on another project that contains service classes, model objects, or persistence logic.*

Hence, a local *"patch"*, i.e. using a local `-SNAPSHOT` version of a local Maven build of the dependency is one possibility.

#### UPDATE

Another one is [Performing a Snapshot Deployment](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#performing-a-snapshot-deployment) to [Sonatype's `snapshots` repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/). (Thanks to [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) for the hint!)

Comment: The intention is to provide a shrink-wrapped deliverable to a client. The local snapshot would not be available to consumers of this project besides myself.

Comment: @javadba If you just `mvn install` it resides just in your local repository (Default: `${user.home}/.m2/repository`). If you `mvn deploy` to a [remote repository used as _Internal Repository_](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#Internal_Repositories) it's available for others, too.

Comment: We do not have a common/shared "internal" repository with the client - so it would not seem to be a workable solution.   What both sides may access : the patched fork of the  github repo containing the performance fixes.  Is there a way to reference that fork from maven?

Comment: @javadba Re _"shrink-wrapped deliverable"_: Are you aware of the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)?

Comment: What would be residence/location of the source of the code used by the assembly plugin to create the final uber-jar?  The client needs to be able to build the uber jar on their site - which requires that the performance patch be incorporated on their site as well.

Comment: @javadba The client has to clone the patched fork repository and build the dependency artifact locally. Then it can be assembled in the uber-jar, together with the other project artifacts.

Comment: Yes that is *possible* but not preferred: requires manual steps by the client that would be better not to require.  I did find out there is a way to host our own repo via github.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github.

Comment: What about deploy it to Maven Central or Bintray?

Comment: @khmarbaise You're right. I've never used Central for SNAPSHOTs but it's possible [Performing a Snapshot Deployment](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#performing-a-snapshot-deployment). I'm going to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer as having provided some useful options. But the most direct answer is to use jitpack - and I provided  that answer separately.