# Add external maven dependency which has no repo

Tags: maven

I'm trying to use the captcha library "patchca". It is a maven project which is only hosted on github.

I already tried to add it as maven dependency from a local path, but with this way it requires  system, so it doesn't compile the library into the final jar.

Current dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>patchca</groupId>
    <artifactId>patchca</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/patchca-0.5.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try install this jar into your maven repository http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: You can use Jitpack repository to depend on GitHub projects. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871056/can-i-use-a-github-project-directly-in-maven

Comment: @gtonic Works! Thanks!